# ExpansionListTile Flutter Customization

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, expandablelistview

[image: img]

I have to design this expansion tile and I'm having trouble. Please help. The children take the design of the expansion tile.

```
Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      color: Color(0xff155cb0),
                    ),
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text('Select Time Slot',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15.0)
                      ),
                      trailing: isExpanded1 ?
                      Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,color: Colors.white,size: 33):
                      Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,color: Colors.white,size: 33),
                      onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) => setState(() => this.isExpanded1 = expanding),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(tile1[0]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

But, I am getting this result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St88k.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a design this should help. This is not the exact code for the image you shared.

```
return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ExpandableNotifier(
            child: ScrollOnExpand(
              child: ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(widgetsCategories[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Category()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          );
        },
```

You can also add [this](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) plugin for further customization and code like this :

```
return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),

            child: ExpandableNotifier(
              child: ScrollOnExpand(
                child: ExpandablePanel(
                  theme: ExpandableThemeData(
                    iconColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                    animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),

                ),
                  header: Center(child: Text(widgetsCategories[index], style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5)),
                  //collapsed: Text('dhfhkjdfh', softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
                  expanded: Category(),

                ),

              ),
            ),
          );
```